# Grails 2.3.8 404 when controller/method called

Tags: grails

I have a weird error going on where when I start my Grails application and see the default home page, no matter what controller I click on I get a 404 not found. But if I change my URL mappings file to point a particular controller and method, then the associated view is rendered fine. I tried typing the url as 'controller/method' but that also gave the 404 and I know that the methods aren't being executed because my test log statements don't print. The only way my views are coming up is if I force them using the URL mappings file and then the test log statements in the methods will also print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a URL mapping defined which supports the `controller/action` pattern.

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        // you probably want a mapping like this...
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
        }

        // other mappings here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, that was it. Thanks. I was following the gTunes application coding along with 'The Definitive Guide To Grails 2' and in `Listing 4-53` of that book (page 92). It seems that the URLMappings.groovy file should **entirely** look like listing 4-53, which is why I ended up removing that key line in your answer. I modified the whole file to look like listing 4-53 instead of adding to the file what I see in listing 4-53. That was my mistake.